# Values stop passing after 2nd iteration of loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am creating a multi-stage calculation wherein each time a calculation is finished, it returns a value that is to be used again at the start of the calculation.

In my `main.py`, I have this code:

```
noOfStages = 5
a = 25
b = 5
c = 0
d = 100

for x in range(noOfStages):
    print("------------Stage", x+1, "---------------")
    c = Calculations.add(a, b)
    a = Calculations.subtract(d, c)
```

And in my `calculations.py`:

```
def add(numA, numB):
    x = numA + numB
    return x

def subtract(numA, numB):
    x = numA - numB
    return x
```

During the first loop the value of `a` has changed to 70 and `c` value to 30, which is correct. But as the loop continues, the values of `a` and `c` still remain the same and are not changing as they should.

Comment: Hi, please make this into a [mcve]. We can't tell what anything is doing with functions we can't see. I can only _guess_ what's going on: `GVal` isn't ever modified, so there's no reason `h`, `pamVal`, and `hamVal`—which depend on it—would change either.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you've described. When running your code, my values for `a` at the end of each iteration are: `[70, 25, 70, 25, 70]`. My values for `c` are `[30, 75, 30, 75, 30]`. Running your code, they are indeed changing.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy apologies for that one, I've deduced it to a simpler code since my original code has complicated calculations.

Comment: Wait, are variables `c` and `a` returning a list?

Comment: No, I had to track their values as they ran. They weren't getting printed as-is.

Comment: If you print in your loop at each step you will see the output like Arya. I think your problem is that you are printing only after the loop is over and the first and last iteration are the same numbers.